# huge return set mysql join multiple table one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, parsing, join

ok here is the question, is joining tables worth the huge return set for mysql for more than two tables?(for two tables yes maybe, but for more?)
here is the situation :

```
table : main[
idmain (pk)
someotherid (key)
/*some other fields*/
]
table : main_sub[
idmainsub (pk)
idmain (key)
/*some other fields*/
]
table : main_sub2[
idmainsub2 (pk)
idmain (key)
/*some other fields*/
]
table : main_sub3[
idmainsub3 (pk)
idmain (key)
/*some other fields*/
]
```

so all the three main_sub tables have a one(main) to many(subs_tables) relationship, meaning that one row in main has multiple rows on the other tables.
Here is the question :

```
SELECT * FROM `main`
INNER JOIN `main_sub` ON `main`.`idmain`=`main_sub`.`idmain` 
INNER JOIN `main_sub2` ON `main`.`idmain`=`main_sub2`.`idmain`
INNER JOIN `main_sub3` ON `main`.`idmain`=`main_sub3`.`idmain`
WHERE `main`.`someotherid`=1
vs.
SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE `main`.`someotherid`=1;
and then 
SELECT * FROM `main_sub` WHERE `main_sub`.`idmain`=(idmainfromfirstquery);
SELECT * FROM `main_sub2` WHERE `main_sub2`.`idmain`=(idmainfromfirstquery);
SELECT * FROM `main_sub3` WHERE `main_sub3`.`idmain`=(idmainfromfirstquery);
```

So is the join worth the huge result set and parsing, vs 4 queries? And with even miniature tables, all of the subs contain 5 links each to main, the size of the result set is getting out of control.

Answer (score 0):

One single query will be faster instead of looping:

```
SELECT * FROM `main`
INNER JOIN `main_sub` ON `main`.`idmain`=`main_sub`.`idmain` 
INNER JOIN `main_sub2` ON `main`.`idmain`=`main_sub2`.`idmain`
INNER JOIN `main_sub3` ON `main`.`idmain`=`main_sub3`.`idmain`
WHERE `main`.`someotherid`=1
```

Comment: do not forget to consider memory requirements and data transfer times too, depending on the layout of "main" table (and which fields are actually required) you may end up with at least 4 times the required dataset size. And depending on a number of records requested it can make a lot of difference (sometimes as much as a difference between outOfMemory errors and normal operation).
P.S. It is always best to select the fields that you require as explicit list.

Comment: yeah i know :), i have written here * just for easy of writing and reading ;)